# Twitter button to reply to a tweet

Tags: twitter

I am looking for a way to create a Twitter button which would automatically post a reply to an existing tweet, without the API.

Clicking the button would open a pop up window with a Twitter status form. Tweeting from the window would create a reply, which would have the tweet_id replied to in its metadata.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Twitter's Web Intents for this. You can setup the tweet intent to take a in_reply_to parameter indicating the tweet that is being replied to. It's pretty much as simple as creating an HREF pointing to https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=12345

If you incude Twitter's optional Javascript, the HREF will become a pop-up automatically and you can further track the events.